# Can I specify a specific account or "From" address in a command line for Thunderbird?

Tags: command-line, bash, thunderbird, cygwin

I am trying to create a bash script that will allow me to send a batch of emails out.  I am using Cygwin, Windows XP and Thunderbird 3.1.3. I have the script generating an email just fine.  The problem that I am having is that I have several email accounts set up in Thunderbird, and I wish to use a different account than the one that is selected by the command line.  I only have one profile set up.

The command line that I arrive at is as follows:

```
thunderbird -compose "to=$strEmailAdd,subject=$SUBJ,attachment='file:///d:/docs/attach/file_to_attach.doc',body='$BODY'"
```

Is there a way to specify the account that the email is coming from or at the very least, specify a 'from' address?  I have tried using "from" and "reply-to" as fields to no avail.

Comment: Not on topic, but mixing `$SUBJ` and `$strEmailAdd` in the same code is ugly.

Comment: `$SUBJ` and `$BODY` are constants.  `$strEmailAdd` is not.  That is why I did it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Thunderbird, it's not designed for batch usage. There are plenty SMTP clients such as [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) or [sendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/).

(msmtp implements a `sendmail` interface, so it only accepts premade MIME messages)

Comment: Normally, I would agree with you and would use one of those options.  But, I need to be able to (possibly) edit the messages after they are generated.